# Is it possible to bound the L2 norm of the gradient of a divergent by the L2 norm of the Lapacian?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions

Is it possible to show for $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$
that
$$\||\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)|\|_2^2\leq C\||\Delta u|\|_2^2?$$

Here $\||f|\|_2$ is the norm in $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ and derivatives are taken in the sense of distributions.

Comment: Yes and this follows from the scalar case: $\|D^2 u\|_2 =\|\Delta u\|_2$ where $(D^2 u)$ is the Hessian matrix of $u$. Having this, $\|D^2_{ik}u_i\|_2^2 \leq \|\Delta u_i\|_2^2$ for $i=1,2,3$ which gives the inequality componentwise.